# BufferedWriter not writing to file

Tags: java, file-io

I am making a program, and I need to add a list of random 6-digit ids to a file. Currently whenever I run this portion of the program, nothing is added to the file. What exactly am I doing wrong so that the code does not write to the file? I checked and made sure that all the random number are definitely being generated.

```
static HashSet<Integer> idHashList = 
        new HashSet<>();

public static void createIds(){
    File writeId = new File("peopleIDs.txt");
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(writeId,true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            out.write(People.genRand());
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

protected static int genRand(){
    while(true){
        int rand = ((int) ((Math.random() * (899999))+100000));
        if(idHashList.add(rand)){
            return rand;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Does that compile? It looks like you have two methods that are the same. 2) Why post about idHashList when it's not used anywhere in your code? 3) Are you sure that `People.genRand()` is doing what you think? Have you tried printing out what it returns and then writing it to file just to test things?

Comment: Woops! @HovercraftFullOfEels copyed the same thing twice :P. Fixed it now

Comment: @TomaszGawel Why? `flush()` happens automatically in `close().` See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably writes to a file, but not the one you think. Java will write to the `peopleIDs.txt` file in the current directory. The current directory is the directory from which the `java` command is executed.

If you launch the program from your IDE, check the run configuration to see which current directory it uses. If you really don't know, then search for `peopleIDs.txt` on your hard drive to find out.

That said, the `close()` should be in a finally block. Or even better, you should use the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construct.

Comment: Can confirm that all files with the name `peopleIds.txt` are empty. I am using NetBeans, and they also have a file directory with a file of the same name that is empty.

Comment: Then either you have an exception, but didn't see the error message, or `genRand()` returns an empty string, or the method is never called.

Comment: I am printing my exception, so I would have seen if there was one, and as I stated above, the numbers are most definitely being generated, as they show up in the command line when a print statement is added before `return rand;`. And for this to happen, the method would have had to have been called :P.

Comment: Then the only possibility I see is that some other method resets the file after this method is called.

Comment: Hmmm. I now did something, and the whole file is filled with random Chinese-looking character. Any ideas?

Comment: You're writing random chars to the file. So you should expect it to be filled with random chars. Read the javadoc of write(). It doesn't print the decimal representation of an int. It writes a char to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the wrong method. `BufferedWriter.write(int)` only writes a `char.` Check the Javadoc. If you want to write the integer as four bytes in binary, you need `DataOutputStream.writeInt().` If you want to write it as a string, you need `BufferedWriter.write(""+People.genRand()),` possibly followed by `BufferedWriter.newLine().`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fill your file like next:

```
PrintWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new PrintWriter("peopleIDs.txt", "UTF-8");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        writer.println(genRand());
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
} finally {
    if(writer != null){
        writer.close();
    }
}
```